# SQL join all values whos items price > 10

Tags: sql

I have the following two tables:

Items:

| id | price | shop_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10.22 | 1 | apple |
| 2 | 10.50 | 1 | pear |
| 3 | 10 | 2 | orange |
| 4 | 9 | 2 | apricot |

Shops:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fruit-shop |
| 2 | grocery-shop |

I am trying to get all the shops that have EVERY item price > 10. I want to retrieve all the items associated with that shop.

For example, based on the above tables I would have:

| name | item_name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fruit-shop | apple | 10.22 |
| fruit-shop | pear | 10.50 |

I have tried using the following query:

```sql
SELECT items.shop_id
FROM items
GROUP BY items.shop_id
HAVING min(items.price) > 10
```

This returns back the correct `shop_id` although then when I try and join and achieve the final goal, all the other shops are also joined and not just shops who's ALL items price are greater than 10.

How to achieve this?

Comment: **Exactly** what RDBMS are you using? Include the edition and version.

Comment: "then when I try and join and achieve the final goal" - **how** are you doing the `JOIN`? Please post your query where you have the `JOIN`. (The `JOIN` needs to be done in an outer-query or CTE: you cannot do the `JOIN` in the same single query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT shops.name, items.name AS item_name, items.price
FROM items JOIN shops ON items.shop_id = shops.id
WHERE shops.id IN (SELECT items.shop_id
        FROM items
        GROUP BY items.shop_id
        HAVING min(items.price) > 10);
```

Comment: BTW, it is fine to replace `IN` with `=SOME`.

Answer (score 1):

- It's a 2 step problem:

  1. Group all `Items` by their `shop_id` and find the `MIN` price of all items in that shop.

     - Your query does this already.
  2. Then `JOIN` those `shop_id` values with the items that shop has.

     - This needs to be done in an outer-query or CTE.

Like so:

```
WITH shopsWithAllItemsPricedOver10 (
    SELECT
        items.shop_id
    FROM
        items
    GROUP BY
        items.shop_id
    HAVING
        MIN( items.price ) > 10
)
SELECT
    i.*
FROM
    items AS i
    INNER JOIN shopsWithAllItemsPricedOver10 AS s ON s.shop_id = i.shop_id
ORDER BY
    i.shop_id,
    i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Exists logic works nicely here:

```sql
SELECT id, name
FROM Shops s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Items i
                  WHERE i.shop_id = s.id AND
                        i.price <= 10);
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e31128ebaf2e47ff7abff2aac5f1e363) showing that the logic is working.

Answer (score -1):

"I am trying to get all the shops that have EVERY item price > 10. "

Would an INNER JOIN work for you here?

```
SELECT * FROM Shops s
INNER JOIN Items i
ON s.id = i.shop_id
WHERE i.price > 10
```

This will return all columns from the Shops table where the Item price is > 10.

Comment: This query will incorrectly include Shops that have items priced below `10` because this query only checks to see if the Shop has **any** items with `price > 10` instead of **all** items.

Comment: @Dai sorry you're right, i misunderstood the question. will rethink :)